# Get header info from php://input

Tags: php

I have a file(image) from  device that is send via put

```
PUT /r.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PHS/2.0.6
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Name: cam20141020084031.jpg,10001019
Content-Length: 35183
Expect: 100-continue
```

This is how I get picture that was send:

```
$res = file_get_contents("php://input");

$file = fopen('1.jpg', "w");
fputs($file, $res);
fclose($file);
```

I need to get content-name separately too. I can't find anywhere how can I get it. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

```
$res = file_get_contents("php://input");
$vars=parse_str($res,$post_vars);
$headers = getallheaders();
$contentName=$headers['Content-Name'])
$file = fopen('1.jpg', "w");
$fileVar= fopen('1.txt', "w");
fputs($file, $res);
fputs($fileVar,$res);
fclose($fileVar);
fclose($file);
```

Strange, but this code seems to be loading forever.

**UPDATE 1**
When I print_r it I understand that it's not headers of put request it's headers of page. Not what I need.

Comment: [This](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php) should help.

Comment: Aren't this some variables of put query (not headers)?

Comment: @Prasanth there is mention of headers on that page

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function, which exists for sole purpose of retrieving request headers:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
var_dump($headers['Content-Name']);
```

Note that it might be best to preprocess keys to take care of headers such as `Content-name` (note the change of letter case near `-`).

Comment: When I print_r it I understand that it's not headers of image it's headers of page. Not what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by headers of image? Do you mean information such as image width and height, and its format? In that case, you might want to look at [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and its family, or for advanced queries, [ImageMagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: I have a put request. And I should get it's headers if I use getallheaders it shows header of page where it is called.